# convert a string to a variant in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, variant

I have this current code, which types "AAPL" into an excel sheet, and the returns the corresponding value.

I would like to make it so that after `cout << "Ticker: ";` i can type in a ticker symbol (such as AAPL) and use this as the `variant_t ticker = "xxx".` I tried doing so by using `string` but i get an error that says cannot convert from `'std::string to const _variant_t &'` Is there anyway to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
 XL->Workbooks->Open(L"F:\\xxx\\Desktop\\fxxxx.xlsx");
 Excel::RangePtr pRange = pSheet->Cells;

 cout << "Ticker: ";
 variant_t ticker = "AAPL";

 pRange->Item[2][1] = ticker;
 double value = pRange->Item[2][2];
 cout << "\n Value = " << value << endl;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `ticker.SetString(str.c_str())` should do the job.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I tried adding this in various lines, but get an error, where exactly where i put it?

Comment: Somewhere between `variant_t ticker;` and  `pRange->Item .. = ticker;`. Of course `str` should be whatever your std::string input is called. And you probably want to do that AFTER you've read in the string, or it won't have the right effect. ;)

Comment: You may want to add your answer as an "answer" (makes the code much more readable)- and if you think I did enoug to help you get there, "accept" my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code:

```
    XL->Workbooks->Open(L"F:\\xx\\Desktop\\xxz.xlsx");                              //Open databse
    Excel::_WorksheetPtr pSheet = XL->ActiveSheet;                                      //Point to Active Sheet
    Excel::RangePtr pRange = pSheet->Cells;                                             //Point to Active Cells
    cout << " Ticker: ";                                                                //Prompt Ticker
    string tick;                                                                        //Define string "tick" to store ticker
    cin >> tick;                                                                        //Store ticker
    variant_t ticker;                                                                   //Define variant to be used for ticker
    ticker.SetString(tick.c_str());                                                     //Convert string to variant                                 
    pRange->Item[2][1] = ticker;                                                        //Write ticker to cell
    double bi = pRange->Item[2][2];                                                     //Read Beta, store as "bi"
    cout << "\n Beta = " << bi << endl;                                                 //Return Value
    XL->Application->Quit();
```